# How can I get past the SettingWithCopyWarning below?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm new to Python and I keep getting the same error on a piece of code.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
for title in paper_alias.keys():
    alias_ix = paper_alias[title]
    papers['PaperAliasId'][alias_ix] = [papers.Id[alias_ix[0]]] * len(alias_ix)
    papers['PaperAliasSize'][alias_ix] = [len(alias_ix)] * len(alias_ix)
```

When I get to the lines

```
papers['PaperAliasId'][alias_ix] = [papers.Id[alias_ix[0]]] * len(alias_ix)
papers['PaperAliasSize'][alias_ix] = [len(alias_ix)] * len(alias_ix)
```

it gives me the following error

**main**:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Any suggestions of a way to bypass this warning (I'm not worried about losing the information) or different code to use that would do the same thing without the error? Thanks.

Comment: Side note: If paper_alias is a dict, you can write: `for title, alias_ix in paper_alias.items():`. Or even `for alias_ix in paper_alias.values():` if you don't need `title`.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead:

```
papers.loc[alias_ix, 'PaperAliasId']
```

following the `.loc[row_indexer, column_index]` format explained in the docs you've linked above.

Comment: I think `PaperAliasId` is a column, so it's rather `papers.loc[alias_ix, 'PaperAliasId']`.